# missing : after property id in JQuery.inArray(value, array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm getting a firebug error:

missing : after property id
error source line:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons)){
```

This is the surrunding code:

Edited post with update as I was unclear.
I am trying to create a framework for creating dialogues for a project.
In the dialogs there can be four predefined buttons.
The mmDialogButton is my attempt to an ENUM class.
The if statement is there to enable the buttons the user wanted to use in the dialog.

Here is some more code to illustrate.

mmDialog.js

```
...

function mmDialog(title, spawnerId, widget, buttons){
...
$dialog.html(widget.getInitialHTML())
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: title + ' <img id="myJquerySpinner" />',
            buttons: {
                if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons)){
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                }
                if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.NEXT, buttons)){
                    "Next": function() {
                        widget.doNext();
                    },
                }
                if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.PREVIOUS, buttons)){
                    "Previous": function() {
                        widget.doPrevious();
                    },
                }
                if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.OK, buttons)){
                    "Ok": function() {
                        widget.doOk();
                    }
                }
            }...
```

mmDialogButton.js

```
function mmDialogButton(){  // Constructor

}

mmDialogButton.CANCEL = function() { return "mmDBCancel"; };
mmDialogButton.OK = function() { return "mmDBOk"; };
mmDialogButton.NEXT = function() { return "mmDBNext"; };
mmDialogButton.PREVIOUS = function() { return "mmDBPrevious"; };
```

jsp/html page

```
            var title = "Test Dialog";
            var spawnerId = "myJqueryStarter";

            var mmDialogButtons = new Array();
            mmDialogButtons[0] = mmDialogButton.CANCEL; 
            mmDialogButtons[1] = mmDialogButton.OK; 
            mmDialogButtons[2] = mmDialogButton.NEXT; 
            mmDialogButtons[3] = mmDialogButton.PREVIOUS; 

            myPublishWidget = new mmPublishWidget();
            myDialogPublishWidget = new mmDialogWidget(myPublishWidget);
            myDialog = new mmDialog(title, spawnerId, myDialogPublishWidget , mmDialogButtons);
```

Comment: The second code snippet has syntax errors. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) retuns `-1` when an item isn't found.  `if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons) != -1)`

Comment: You have a buttons object containing some functions presumably and other variable called "buttons" defined in the same scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to execute the "close" only if CANCEL is in buttons, if it's the case you can write:

```
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
              if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons)){
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
            },
    ....
```

EDIT:

you can define the buttons dictionary beforehand as you like, the pass it to `.dialog(`:

```
dialog_buttons = {}

if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons)){
 dialog_buttons[Cancel] = function() {
                             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                          }
}

if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.NEXT, buttons)){
 dialog_buttons["Next"] = function() {
                             widget.doNext();
                          }
}

if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.PREVIOUS, buttons)){
 dialog_buttons["Previous"] = function() {
                                 widget.doPrevious();
                              }
}

if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.OK, buttons)){
 dialog_buttons["Ok"] = function() {
                           widget.doOk();
                        }
}

$dialog.html(widget.getInitialHTML())
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: title + ' <img id="myJquerySpinner" />',
            buttons: dialog_buttons
            }...
```

Comment: Thanks very much worked fine. Only small this was that Cancel was undefined and that I had to change the if condition to != -1. JQuery should return a boolean with such a method name :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
buttons: {
    if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons)){
      Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
```

should probably be:

```
buttons: (function() {
    if(jQuery.inArray(mmDialogButton.CANCEL, buttons))
      return {
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
       };
       return null;
    })()
```

though it's hard to tell. What it *looks* like you're trying to do is conditionally set that "buttons" property to some object with a labeled handler (that little "close" function).  However, the code you posted is syntactically nonsensical.  The change I made wraps the "inArray" test in an anonymous function that returns the button object only when that test is `true`.

Again, I'm just guessing that that's what you were trying to do.